# missing argument edit data with upload image in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i think i have correctly writting this code but i get a problem on missing argument and i selected file image to upload but i get error too like this.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for Data_guru::edit()

Filename: tim_monitoring/Data_guru.php

Line Number: 90

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\sdb\application\controllers\tim_monitoring\Data_guru.php
Line: 90
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\sdb\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

You did not select a file to upload.
```

thanks for your answer

## My Controller

```
public function edit($id) {
$this->form_validation->set_rules('nama_guru','Nama Guru','required');      
$this->form_validation->set_rules('alamat','Alamat','required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $data = array ('title'  => 'Edit Data Guru',
                       'detail' => $this->monitoring_model->detail_guru($id),
                       'isi'    => 'monitoring/edit_guru_view'
                       );
    $this->load->view('monitoring/layout/wrapper',$data);
    //Kalau Tidak Ada Error Data Guru DiUpdate
    }else{
            $config['file_name']            = $this->input->post('nama_guru');
            $config['upload_path']          = './assets/image/guru/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 3000;
            $config['max_width']            = 3000;
            $config['max_height']           = 3000;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('foto_guru'))
            {
                    echo $this->upload->display_errors();
            }
            else
            {
                    $gbr = $this->upload->data();
                    $data = array(
                            'foto_guru'     => $gbr['file_name'],
                            'id_guru'       => $this->input->post('id_guru'),
                            'nama_guru'     => $this->input->post('nama_guru'),
                            'jenis_kelamin' => $this->input->post('jen_kel'),
                            'alamat'        => $this->input->post('alamat'),
                            'tempat_lahir'  => $this->input->post('tempat_lahir'),
                            'tgl_lahir'     => $this->input->post('tgl_lahir'),
                            'no_hp'         => $this->input->post('no_hp'),
                            'username'      => $this->input->post('username'),
                            'password'      => $this->input->post('password')
                    );

        $this->monitoring_model->edit_guru($data);
        redirect(base_url().'tim_monitoring/data_guru');
    }
 }
}
```

## My Model

```
 //Menampilkan Detail Guru Di Halaman Edit Guru
public function detail_guru($id) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('t_guru', array('id_guru' => $id));
    return $query->row_array();
}

//Update Data Guru Setelah Di Edit Di Halaman Edt
public function edit_guru($data) {
    $this->db->where('id_guru',$data['id_guru']);
    return $this->db->update('t_guru',$data);
}
```

## My View

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url() ?>/tim_monitoring/data_guru/edit"    class="form-horizontal" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Nama Guru</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input type="text" name="nama_guru" class="form-control" placeholder="Nama Guru" value="<?php echo $detail['nama_guru'] ?>" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Tempat Lahir</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input type="text" name="tempat_lahir" class="form-control" placeholder="Tempat Lahir"  value="<?php echo $detail['tempat_lahir'] ?>" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Tanggal Lahir</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input type="date" name="tgl_lahir" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $detail['tgl_lahir'] ?>" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Alamat</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <textarea name="alamat" class="form-control" rows="4" required><?php echo $detail['alamat'] ?></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">No Handphone</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input type="number" name="no_hp" class="form-control" placeholder="No Handphone" value="<?php echo $detail['no_hp'] ?>" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Foto</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="file" name="foto_guru" id="exampleInputFile" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Username</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo $detail['username'] ?>" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" value="<?php echo $detail['password'] ?>" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Jenis Kelamin</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input type="radio" name="jen_kel" value="L"><label>&nbsp;Laki - Laki</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="radio" name="jen_kel" value="P"><label>&nbsp;Perempuan</label>
        </div>
      </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="id_guru" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $detail['id_guru'] ?>" required>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ubah Data</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: You need to pass id to form action on page load. `<form action="<?php echo base_url() ?>/tim_monitoring/data_guru/edit/<?php echo $id;//this one you have to pass from controller when page is loaded?>"    class="form-horizontal" method="post">`.

Comment: missing argument not display again when i use your code, but upload image and input data still not changed in database. error on upload image "You did not select a file to upload". thanks for your answer mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see **edit()** Method of **tim_monitoring/Data_guru.php** that's must be require to pass one parameter as value of variable **$id**.

So, you need to add following **URL** in form's action

**`action="<?php echo base_url() ?>/tim_monitoring/data_guru/edit/<?php echo $detail['id_guru'] ?>"`**

For upload image form must require attribute **`enctype="multipart/form-data`**"

Comment: in the upload image i get error The file type and size you are attempting to upload is not allowed. me uploading my file image is not large than my config but why i get this error. in the insert data i use this code and can, but not in edit. thanks for your answer mate